# Guideline 17.2. What is the correct way?

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

My App is getting rejections showing same issue that it is violating `guideline 17.2`. What is correct way to implement `auto-renewable subscription` with it?

In my app there is a download button which alerts user to login or register. Then after filling registration form user proceeds for payment. Registration form has fields like `email, password, phone and username.`

App got rejected saying it is asking for user's personal info, so I made email and phone number as optional fields. I put a note to review team also. App still got rejected showing same reason.

I have few questions:

- `Guideline 17.2` is only for `IAP OR Auto-Renewable Subscriptions`? Because I have created several apps before asking user to put there email and phone, never got rejection.
- I am asking user to do paid registration to download the `PDF`. If I revert it, like first user will register for free then he will opt to pay and download every `PDF`.

Please help, `IAP` sucks.

Comment: because you have asked personal information for the subscribing your service – as the 17.2 says: _"Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, **in order to function** will be rejected"_, I highlighted the key-point here. rejecting your app was obvious.

Comment: so shall I first do registration then IAP on every download? App will still have limited functionality until he downloads. :(

Comment: if you need those information desperately for subscribing to your service, that better way is you need to put the registration procedure _outside_ of the app (e.g. website), and the app can present the login feature only – it is hard to tell because I don't know what is your marketing strategy for that app.

Comment: yes you are right. I can launch the app that way, but it is not fulfilling the requirement :(.Can you tell me 17.2 is only for IAP or any app? I am too confused.

Comment: the 17.2 is in general. if you just ask those private information as requirement for granting access to the app's features, you app will be rejected certainly – no matter whether you ask money beside or not.